# Changing navigationItem.rightBarButton isn't resulting in visual changes

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

For whatever reason my `rightBarButton` is 1. not going away when I set the `rightBarButton` to nil and 2. not changing when I set it to another `UIBarButtonItem`.

I can successfully change the title on the fly so I don't suspect the inherited navigation controller is the problem.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Settings"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

This simply does nothing and the right bar button remains as a button with text "Cancel".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are have some problem with `image: UIImage(named: "Settings")`. Check the name of the image or try to use this to fill a `UIImageView`

EDIT:
this the code that I used to fill a item with an image and act like a button

```
   //set frame
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TorchView.showRank(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "question"),  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(TorchView.tapQuestion))

        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, barButton]
```

In this case I am using 2 rightButtons

Comment: Well even when I manually add a right button in the IB and change its name to anything that won't show up. So I'm pretty sure the button is fine as no changes are showing up on the simulator.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example that I am using in my code